# Springboot multiple datasource does not autogenerate schemas

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to manage in SpringBoot two datasources (MariaDB 10.5). Leveraging some tutorials I came to this solution. I define  two datasource configurations, one for "users" and one for "data". The main application is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{ 
  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext appContext;
  @Autowired
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean dataEntityManagerFactory;
  @Autowired
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean userEntityManagerFactory;

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {   
   SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);       
  }

  @PostConstruct 
  @Transactional
  public void postConstruct()
  {    
   Todo p = new Todo("admin");  //main datasource      
   Privilege s = new Privilege("admin"); //user datasource            
   userEntityManagerFactory.getObject().createEntityManager().persist(s);
   dataEntityManagerFactory.getObject().createEntityManager().persist(p);
  }     
  
 }   
}
```

where the line

```
userEntityManagerFactory.getObject().createEntityManager().persist(s);
```

throws the exception

```
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: it.unict.spring.application.persistence.model.user.Privilege
```

and prevents the deployment when the database contains the schemas "data" and "users", whereas if the database does not contain such schemas, the latter and the related tables are not auto-generated.

The datasource configuration for users data source is:

```
package it.unict.spring.application.configurations.user;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfigUser
 {   
   @Value("${spring.datasource2.driver-class-name}") 
   private String driver;
   @Value("${spring.datasource2.url}")                   
   private String urlUser; 
   @Value("${spring.datasource2.username}") 
   private  String username;
   @Value("${spring.datasource2.password}") 
   private  String password;    


   @Bean("userSource")  
   public DataSource getUserSource()
    {
      return DataSourceBuilder.create()
      .driverClassName(driver)
      .url(urlUser)
      .username(username)
      .password(password)
      .build(); 
    }   
   }
```

the second one for data:

```
package it.unict.spring.application.configurations.data;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfigData
{   
 @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}") 
 private String driver;
 @Value("${spring.datasource.url}") 
 private  String urlData;
 @Value("${spring.datasource.username}") 
 private  String username;
 @Value("${spring.datasource.password}") 
 private  String password;    

@Bean("dataSource")  
@Primary
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
      .driverClassName(driver)
      .url(urlData)
      .username(username)
      .password(password)          
      .build(); 
}     
}
```

The transaction manager for users (thanks to stackeoverflow):

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
   basePackages = {"it.unict.spring.application.repository.user", 
  "it.unict.spring.application.persistence.model.user"},
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "userEntityManagerFactory",
   transactionManagerRef = "userTransactionManager"
    )
   public class JpaTransactUser
   {

    @Bean("userEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
 userEntityManagerFactory(
                            @Qualifier("userSource") DataSource dataSource,
                            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) 
{
    
      final HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", 
      "org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect");
     properties.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", "create");
     properties.put("spring.jpa.generate-ddl", "true");

    
       return builder
      .dataSource(dataSource)   
      .properties(properties)
      .packages("it.unict.spring.application.repository.user", "it.unict.spring.application.persistence.model.user")          
      .build();
   }

    @Bean("userTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager userTransactionManager(
     @Qualifier("userEntityManagerFactory") 
     LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean topicsEntityManagerFactory)
{
          return new JpaTransactionManager(Objects.requireNonNull(topicsEntityManagerFactory.getObject()));
}
```

}

The  transaction manager for data:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
 basePackages = {"it.unict.spring.application.repository.data",
             "it.unict.spring.application.persistence.model.data"},
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "dataEntityManagerFactory",
  transactionManagerRef = "dataTransactionManager"
)
public class JpaTransactData
  {

  @Bean("dataEntityManagerFactory") 
  @Primary
   public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
     dataEntityManagerFactory(
                            @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource 
     dataSource,
                            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) 
   {
    
      final HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      properties.put("hibernate.dialect", 
   "org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect");
     properties.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", "create");
     properties.put("spring.jpa.generate-ddl", "true");
    
       return builder
      .dataSource(dataSource)
      .properties(properties)             
      .packages("it.unict.spring.application.repository.data", "it.unict.spring.application.persistence.model.data")
      .build();
}

@Bean("dataTransactionManager")    
public PlatformTransactionManager dataTransactionManager(
@Qualifier("dataEntityManagerFactory") 
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean topicsEntityManagerFactory)
{
        return new JpaTransactionManager(Objects.requireNonNull(topicsEntityManagerFactory.getObject()));
}
```

}

For the sake of completeness the application.property files is:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/data
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver


spring.datasource2.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/users
spring.datasource2.username=root
spring.datasource2.password=root
spring.datasource2.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

The pom is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
    
<groupId>it.unict.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringApplication</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>SpringApplication</name>        
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <start-class>Application</start-class>
</properties>
<dependencies>
        
        
        
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>         
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>                                 
                     
                                   
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
                <artifactId> mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            </dependency>   
            
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>               
          
                                                                          
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>                 
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
           <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>   
           </dependency>
           
            <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>            
        </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
            <finalName>SpringApplication</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
     <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
      <configuration>
       <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
      </configuration>
     </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

I do not past repositorie and models  files seems the problem sees related with the configuration of the data sources.

Edit:
I modified the configurations by adding suitable JpaVendorAdapter, one for data and one for user as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
   basePackages = {"it.unict.spring.application.repository.data",
              
   "it.unict.spring.application.persistence.model.data"},
   entityManagerFactoryRef = "dataEntityManagerFactory",
   transactionManagerRef = "dataTransactionManager"
   )
    public class JpaTransactData
       {
         @Bean("dataEntityManagerFactory") 
         @Primary
         public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
         dataEntityManagerFactory(
                            @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource 
           dataSource,                                
                            @Qualifier("dataJpaVendor") 
           JpaVendorAdapter adapter)
          {        
              Properties properties = new Properties();
              properties.put("hibernate.dialect", 
              "org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect");
     
           
    properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action","create");
     
    properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target", "create.sql");
    properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-source=metadata", "adapter");
     

               LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lem=new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
lem.setPackagesToScan("it.unict.spring.application.repository.data", 
    "it.unict.spring.application.persistence.model.data");
     lem.setJpaProperties(properties);
     lem.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
     


  lem.setPackagesToScan("it.unict.spring.application.repository.data", "it.unict.spring.application.persistence.model.data");
     lem.setDataSource(dataSource);
     return lem;
}

@Bean("dataTransactionManager")
@Primary    
public PlatformTransactionManager dataTransactionManager(
@Qualifier("dataEntityManagerFactory") 
  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean topicsEntityManagerFactory)
{
    return new JpaTransactionManager(Objects.requireNonNull(topicsEntityManagerFactory.getObject()));
}

@Bean("dataJpaVendor")
@Primary
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter()
{
 HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
 hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
 hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true); //Auto creating scheme when true
 hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);//Database type
 return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
}  }
```

I also added "createDatabaseIfNotExist=true" to the jdbc url and now databases are created but null values are added instead of the desired value.

Comment: The properties don't do anything. As it isn't Spring Boot setting them but you. Spring Boot will set the proper Hibernate properties for `pring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` and `spring.jpa.generate-ddl`, so you need to set the proper hibernate properties **not** the Spring Boot properties.

Comment: I modified the configuration and added "createDatabaseIfNotExist=true" to jdbc url. Schemas are create but the exception is generated and only null values are added to the database.

Comment: That won't change a thing, that still will not let hibernate generate the schema..

Comment: Any link with a tutorial on how to set things up?

Comment: You are changing your question whilst things are being answered. So I have no clue on what you want to achieve now, which error is being throw or what null values are inserted you aren't expecting?

Comment: Thanks to my last changes databases are set up automatically but null values are added instead of the given ones.

Comment: If there are no values your mapping is wrong.

Comment: I think that it is going out of topic, since the initial problem is solved , I close this one. Thanks